# OpenCV Java - How to crop a circle detected in a image

Tags: java, android, image, opencv, detect

I am using the following algorithm from OpenCV.

1) Detect circles in the image.

2) Draw the detected circle on the image. (This is already done, the code is as follow).

3) Crop the detected region.

But, the question is how can i crop out this detected region on the image?

Answer (score 3):

**1. create a mask:**

```
Mat mask = new Mat(src.rows(), src.cols(), CvType.CV_8U, Scalar.all(0));
```

**2. Draw the circle on that mask (set thickness to -1 to fill the circle):**

```
Imgproc.circle(mask, center, radius, new Scalar(255,255,255), -1, 8, 0 );
```

**3. Copy the image using the mask:**

```
Mat masked = new Mat();
src.copyTo( masked, mask );
```

**4. Apply Threshold**

```
Mat thresh = new Mat();
Imgproc.threshold( mask, thresh, 1, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY );
```

**5. Find contour**

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
Imgproc.findContours(thresh, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

**6. Crop**

```
Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(0));
Mat cropped = masked.submat(rect);
```

#### Full code example (OpenCV 3.4):

[image]

```
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.highgui.HighGui;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class HoughCirclesRun {
    public void run(String[] args) {
        String filename = "smartie.png";
        // Load an image
        Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread(filename, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);
        // Check if image is loaded fine
        if( src.empty() ) {
            System.out.println("Error opening image!");
        }

        Mat gray = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(src, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Imgproc.medianBlur(gray, gray, 5);
        Mat circles = new Mat();
        Imgproc.HoughCircles(gray, circles, Imgproc.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.0,
                (double)gray.rows()/16, // change this value to detect circles with different distances to each other
                100.0, 30.0, 1, 30); // change the last two parameters (min_radius & max_radius) to detect larger circles

        Mat mask = new Mat(src.rows(), src.cols(), CvType.CV_8U, Scalar.all(0));

        for (int x = 0; x < circles.cols(); x++) {
            double[] c = circles.get(0, x);
            Point center = new Point(Math.round(c[0]), Math.round(c[1]));
            // circle outline
            int radius = (int) Math.round(c[2]);
            Imgproc.circle(mask, center, radius, new Scalar(255,255,255), -1, 8, 0 );
        }

        Mat masked = new Mat();
        src.copyTo( masked, mask );

        // Apply Threshold
        Mat thresh = new Mat();
        Imgproc.threshold( mask, thresh, 1, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY );

        // Find Contour
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
        Imgproc.findContours(thresh, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        // Crop
        Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(0));
        Mat cropped = masked.submat(rect);

        HighGui.imshow("Cropped circle", cropped);
        HighGui.waitKey();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
public class CropCircle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Load the native library.
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        new HoughCirclesRun().run(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Cartucho, Halo, i had tried it on my app. It doesn't work, it only return me with a black color image.  i couldn't import highGui. What i wish to do is to crop out the portion of the circle in the image. I do not want the rest of the portion. Could you help me please. Thank you

Comment: @ Joao Cartucho thanks for your reply. however, i tried the codes, it doesn't crop only the circle portion from the image and eliminate the rest. It returns with a black background and circle detected outlines on the image.

Comment: @awa I finally understood what you want, I edited the code. Have a look!

Comment: @ Joao Cartucho, really appreciate your help. I had tried your code on my program. However it still seems to have some issue. Just wandering if i am to do something like, 1) the user clicks on "detect circle" 2) the program respond with the outline o the detected circle in the image 3) the user clicks on "crop" 4) the program then crop only the portion that is in the within the detected circle outline.  Is it possible to do something like this? Best if you can modified it from my posted code. Much thanks

Comment: @awa yeah you can do that by creating a GUI that will call the OpenCV code. You can do that using JavaFX.

Comment: @ Joao Cartucho, i am currently working this function on android studio. If i would use the algorithm that i post. How can i work from there ? is there a way to pass the co-ordinates detected by my algorithm and pass these co-ordinates to crop it out ?

Comment: @ Joao Cartucho, i have no idea how to proceed with it. please help. thank you

Comment: Cartucho , i am getting this error (OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols) in void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean), file /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/u)                                  when i try to convert the "cropped" mat back to a bitmap image using Utils.matToBitmap

Comment: @awa I answered your initial question. Could you please start a new post with the new questions you have? (: